# Counting the permutations of a set in which some elements can be repeated

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose I have $n$ cards that I've arbitrarily placed into $p$ piles, possibly of different sizes.  The cards are available in $c$ colors, and all cards with the same color are considered identical.

After building these piles, I need to draw a hand of $k$ cards without replacing any of them.  If $k > n$, then I'll just do the best I can and draw $n$ cards.  There are no restrictions on what cards I can pick, except that I can only draw cards from the top of a pile.  **How many hands can I draw, if the order of the cards in the hand is important?**

**EDIT:** My understanding of my problem has changed, so I've changed some details of this question.  The answer may be very different as a result (but no one has yet posted an answer as of this writing).

Comment: There can be no certain answer unless the cards in piles (including their order) are known. For example if the top $k $ cards in every pile are of the same color there is only one possible hand.

Comment: Let's say I know exactly what and where each card is, but I'm still only allowed to draw from the top of the pile.

Comment: But the answer will clearly depend on the exact composition of the piles.  Are you seeking an algorithm that takes as input, the piles, and gives you the no. of hands?

Comment: @antkam Yes, that is correct.  Is that on-topic here?

Comment: I'd say... yes, maybe?  But you might wanna rephrase the question, along the lines of: Given $p$ piles, each being an array $S_p = [S_{p,1}, S_{p,2}, ...]$ and each card is one of $c$ colors etc.  This actually may be an interesting algorithm-design question.

Comment: Funnily enough, it's for a practical problem (deciding how much memory I need to allocate for a search algorithm).